# PostgresSQL default statement for join

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a transactions table, each transaction has an address field which references a row in an address table, each address in the address table has a coinID.

I want to get a sum of all transactions for EVERY coin for a specific user. I don't care about ownership, I want to display every coin in the table regardless if users own it or not.

The problem I have is that if a user has 0 transactions or addresses that belong to a specific coin it is completely missing from the result. I need all coins in a coin table that have 0 transactions or addresses to return with a sum of 0.

```
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN SUM(transactions.amount) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(transactions.amount) END AS balance
FROM coins
Left outer  JOIN addresses ON addresses.coin_id = coins.id
Left outer  JOIN transactions ON transactions.address = addresses.address
Left outer JOIN users ON transactions.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.email = 'matt@test.net'
```

I have tried quite a few combinations of queries but no matter what I do I get 1 of two options

- rows are only returned for coins that the user has a transaction/address for
- rows are returned but contain the balance of all transactions in the database not just the ones belonging to that user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the `WHERE`. If no user was joined, no e-mail address can match and you get the empty set. Try to `CROSS JOIN` the user in question and then `LEFT JOIN` the addresses and transactions.

```
SELECT c.id,
       coalesce(sum(t.amount), 0)
       FROM coins c
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT u.id
                               FROM users u
                               WHERE u.email = 'matt@test.net') u
            LEFT JOIN addresses a
                      ON a.coin_id = c.id
            LEFT JOIN transactions t
                      ON t.address = a.address
                         AND t.user_id = u.id
            GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: Sorry, that was me. I saw the original post, didn't catch the update. In fact, I just posted my own answer (fixing the problem with yours), and then deleted it once I saw you'd dealt with the issue. To make that a bit less futile, here's [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xzwtemBH1qM2ewY25VhxZ7/1) showing how this works.